# Can I give ratings and post review for different Android apps in Google Play directly from my Android app?

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services

I am making an app, in which I want to directly give ratings and post reviews in Google Play for my installed apps.

I am using the Market API to fetch all the data of an app. Is there any way or any API which allows me give ratings and post reviews in Google Play?

Comment: There is no "Market API".

Comment: I doubt it, as it could easily lead to developers giving themselves automatically good ratings; or pushing the users to do so. But if there really is a way I'm interested to know...

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/    it only allows to read the information of apps in google play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such API, sorry. In order for a user to review your app, they must do it in the Google Play app.

However, you can be clever on how you direct users. You could have a pop-up asking if they like your app, with a leading question that determines if the rating will be low or high, directing them to your own feedback system if it is low, and the Play Store if it is high.